# Stange behaviour since upgrade from 2.6.2 to 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

I faced to a strange behaviour while upgrading my application from SpringBoot 2.6.2 to 2.7.0.
I've a starter with autoconfiguration which is responsible of initializing JPA auditing :

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({DataSource.class, AuditorAware.class, SecurityContextHolder.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter({HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ClockSpringConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider", dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider")
public class JpaAuditingSpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () ->
                Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                        .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                        .map(Authentication::getName);
    }

    @Bean
    public DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider(Clock clock) {
        return () ->
                Optional.of(clock)
                        .map(Clock::instant);
    }
}
```

This starter is fine in 2.6.2. But in 2.7.0 the `@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)` avoid the starter to perform initialization.
When i remove the statement all is fine again.

I don't understand why it doesn't work since the update?
Maybe i misused or forgot some statement. The behaviour i attempt to is the autoconfiguration apply only if a datasource bean is registred.

If someone can help me ?

PS : sorry for my english :-)

Comment: If you [enable the debug property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.startup-failure), then Spring Boot outputs the condition evaluation report showing why an auto-configuration was or was not executed. What does it show?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did it and log says :
    JpaAuditingSpringConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource'

So the bean is not found and i don't understand why? and why it was found with 2.6.2...

Comment: Is the `DataSource` being auto-configured? This should in theory work fine as `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` is declared to come after `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. But in 2.7 they have changed the mechanism around auto-configuration and maybe there is a bug. It may help if you change to the new `@AutoConfiguration`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#changes-to-auto-configuration

Comment: I did it but always the same behaviour, the bean Database is not found.
I don't understand :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution, it was a mistake from myself... I put the `@AutoConfigureAfter` on a `@Configuration` imported by the autoconfiguration entrypoint. So i move the statement on the autoconfiguration class and now all is fine.
The new annotation `@AutoConfiguration` will be very usefull to avoid this kinf of mistake.